Count cell value if that pattern matches with two columns in google sheet
enter image description hereHow do I find the count of an value based on condition on two columns?
Here is an example:
So Column E2 and E3 has count 1 and 2 respectively because of number of available Mango and Grapes in row C.
example
I tired some formulas with count and countif, It did not work.


You may try this in Cell_E2:
=countifs(B:B,D2,C:C,"Available")

